# How to compare input from a Scanner to data in a constructor?

Tags: java, oop

So let's say I have the following constructor:

```
    Person(String firstName, String lastName, String address, int contact, int id)
{
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.address = address;
    this.contact = contact;
    this.id = id;
}
```

and I created this to store a couple copies of that object.

```
Person[] test = new Person [5];
    test[0] = new Person("Bruce", "Wayne", "Gotham City", 3143334, 163146549);
test[1] = new Person("Charles", "Xavier", "Washington D.C.", 5094170, 306784107);
test[2] = new Person("Tony", "Stark", "Los Angeles", 9263526, 714508339);
test[3] = new Person("Clark", "Kent", "Smallville", 3786018, 235219986);
test[4] = new Person("Diana", "Prince", "Amazoness Island", 3277004, 424108528);
```

And I want to compare what the user inputs into the scanner with the `id

If it matches one of the IDs, continue the program, else break;

What is a simple way to do this? Thanks.`

Comment: Why do people keep downvoting? ._.

Comment: Because this is very basic stuff; something that you **learn** by looking into tutorials. And beyond that, such low level questions tend to attract a lot of mediocre answers.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to convert your input to int and thenloop over all elements of the array and compare it.

```
 boolean match = false;
    for(int i=0;i<test.length;i++){
        if(input == test[i].getId()){
            match = true;
            break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `Scanner` to read the input and compare it with the elements inside the array as shown in the below code with comments:

```
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = scanner.nextLine();//gives the string
        int inputInt = Integer.parseInt(input);//convert to int
        boolean matchFound = false;//flag to keep the match
        for(int i=0; i<test.length;i++) {//iterate the array
            if(test[i].getId() == inputInt) {//match found
                matchFound = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(!matchFound) {
            //add code here to execute if match found
        } else {
            System.out.println(" MATCH NOT FOUND");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
boolean flag = true;
while(flag){
    int id = sc.nextInt();
    for(Person p : test){
        if(p.id==id){
           flag = true;
           break;
        }
        flag = false;
    }
}
```

This basically has a `while` loop which runs until `flag` is `false`. Within it, we loop through the `Person` array, and check the `id`. If the `id` is found, we make the `flag` true, if not, the loop continues, checking against other `Person` ids. At the end, if `flag` is true, it means we found a match, and thus the `while` loop continues running.

Answer (score -1):

```html
    import java.util.Scanner;

public class MainClass {

   
    static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);



    public static void main(String args[]){

        Person[] test = new Person [5];
        test[0] = new Person("Bruce", "Wayne", "Gotham City", 3143334, 163146549);
        test[1] = new Person("Charles", "Xavier", "Washington D.C.", 5094170, 306784107);
        test[2] = new Person("Tony", "Stark", "Los Angeles", 9263526, 714508339);
        test[3] = new Person("Clark", "Kent", "Smallville", 3786018, 235219986);
        test[4] = new Person("Diana", "Prince", "Amazoness Island", 3277004, 424108528);

        System.out.println("Please enter some id: ");
        int check = in.nextInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
            int contact = test[i].id;
            if (check == contact){
                System.out.println(contact + "is found!");
            }
        }

    }


        static class Person {
        String firstName, lastName, address;
        int id, contact;

            Person(String firstName, String lastName, String address, int contact, int id)
            {
                this.firstName = firstName;
                this.lastName = lastName;
                this.address = address;
                this.contact = contact;
                this.id = id;
            }
       }
}
```